# Is it possible to have different working directories for various commands in the same custom target in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to understand, is it possible to specify multiple working directories for different commands?

I added a custom target called `run_projects`:

```
add_custom_target(run_projects
    COMMAND first_project &
    COMMAND second_project
    COMMAND killall first_project &> /dev/null &
    COMMAND killall second_project &> /dev/null
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

It should run executable projects: first_project + second_project.
The problem is resources of first_project in root directory:
`${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`, but second_project resources is in `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/second_project`

```
my_project:
    resources/ <- resources of first_project outside apps/first_project dir
    second_project/resources/ <- resources of second project inside second_project dir
```

Any chance to make it work via CMake only?

Comment: Create a function and pass working directory as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as documentation goes, no. [The command signature as documented is](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html):

```
add_custom_target(Name [ALL] [command1 [args1...]]
                  [COMMAND command2 [args2...] ...]
                  [DEPENDS depend depend depend ... ]
                  [BYPRODUCTS [files...]]
                  [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
                  [COMMENT comment]
                  [JOB_POOL job_pool]
                  [VERBATIM] [USES_TERMINAL]
                  [COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS]
                  [SOURCES src1 [src2...]])
```

I would split what you're doing into separate custom targets (or custom commands if you don't want the commands to *always run*), and specify the dependencies between them using the `DEPENDS` fields or [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html). That way, you can specify the working directory for each one specifically.

It looks as though you're trying to use shell-specific things like Bash's run-in-background operator (`&`). If you write your commands each in their own custom command / target, as long as the buildsystem generator you have chosen supports building/running targets in parallel, then you will get what you want by default, and it will be cross-platform automatically (instead of depending on the syntax of a specific shell).

---

I did do a quick test on my Ubuntu machine with Ninja and the following:

```
add_custom_target(
cd ALL
COMMAND pwd
COMMAND cd build
COMMAND pwd
COMMAND cd ..
COMMAND pwd
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

, which CMake generates to run as `cd /home/david/code/mine/cmake-playground/16 && pwd && cd build && pwd && cd .. && pwd && echo hi`, which shows that it's possible to `cd` around places in between each command on at least one platform + generator combination.

But you shouldn't rely on this behaviour. It's an internal / implementation detail. The documentation for `add_custom_target`'s `COMMAND` argument says:

> Specify the command-line(s) to execute at build time. If more than one `COMMAND` is specified they will be executed in order, but not necessarily composed into a stateful shell or batch script. (To run a full script, use the [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command or the [`file(GENERATE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command to create it, and then specify a `COMMAND` to launch it.)

Comment: ```add_custom_target(run_projects DEPENDS first_project DEPENDS second_project)```

This thing works if both targets are specified as DEPENDS. But I want to launch only the binary as the second_project:

```add_custom_target(run_projects DEPENDS first_project COMMAND second_project COMMAND killall second_project &> /dev/null WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/second_project)```

DEPENDS and COMMAND for some reason work only separately. Is there some way to run them together?

Comment: @a.wise why are you putting your `DEPENDS` before your `COMMAND`s? I'm not sure if that's a problem, but it's against the documented signature. try following the documented order of arguments.

Comment: I tried changing the order, but it didn't help. Same result

Comment: The problem was with running one of the apps without `&`